# Displaying image from database in webpages

Tags: c#, sql, razor

I am creating a website in visual studio. I want retrieve and display image (of datatype image from sql server database) in webpage. I have a .cshtml page and got the following code to display some of the fields of the table. I am able to display everything except the image datatype column. I am using razor syntax.

MY code

```
@{
var db1 = Database.Open("database1");
var selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM Recipes ORDER BY date";
}
<div class="left-content">
<h5>Recent Posts</h5>
 <table>
    <tbody>
    @foreach(var row in db1.Query(selectQueryString))
    {         
    <tr>
        <td>@row.image</td>
        <td>@row.title</td>
        <td>@row.description</td>
    </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my output in the webpage:

```
Recent Posts
System.Byte[]   testaspform     ufegewu
System.Byte[]   testone     qfeyqo
System.Byte[]   testtwo     oadiufh
```

As you could see the first column show System.Byte[] instead of the image.

Comment: You have to process the byte array and convert it to an image. Do a little research on how to convert a byte[] to an image, it's kinda simple to do. I'll try to post an answer with the code in a few minutes.

Comment: You also have to use an img html tag..

Answer (score 5):

You can't render an image in an html file without using an `<img/>` tag.

What you can do is place an `<img>` tag and create a FileContentResult in your Controller and call it in the source of your  tag using the `@Url.Action()` helper...

==Code==

In your HTML:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("ProcessImage", routeValues: new { imageToProcess = row.image })" />
```

In your Controller:

```
public FileContentResult ProcessImage(byte[] imageToProcess)
{
    return new FileContentResult(imageToProcess, "image/jpeg");
}
```

...

*Make sure to place the ProccessImage method in the same controller as the one that holds the ActionMethod that renders the view you are in, if that's not the case, then use:*

HTML:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("ProcessImage", routeValues: new { controller = "{CONTROLLER_NAME}", imageToProcess = row.image })" />
```

I didn't build the code given above, so you might have to resolve any typo/syntax error...